# Error using timestamp parameter when making GET Curl request

Tags: php, curl

When using a timestamp in date parameters when making GET request using Curl I am getting a **"403 Forbidden"** Error.

This is the code I am using to make the GET request using Curl:

```
         $curl = curl_init($url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
         curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
         $result = curl_exec($curl);
         $http_status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
         curl_close($curl);
```

When using just the date in the parameter it is working as expected:

```
$url = "https://api.unleashedsoftware.com/Customers?modifiedSince=2021-12-20";
```

However, including the time format gives a **"403 Forbidden"** Error.

```
$url = "https://api.unleashedsoftware.com/Customers?modifiedSince=2021-12-20T10:00:10";
```

I also tried this, but also does not work:

```
$url = "https://api.unleashedsoftware.com/Customers?modifiedSince=2021-12-20T10%3A00%3A00";
```

I have tested using the same URL parameters directly into the applications Sandbox to check that it accepts these parameters, which it does and works fine:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried applying proper URL encoding to the parameter value? cURL does not do that for you on its own, when you pass it an already fully assembled URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ':' is not allowed on query, try to use datetime between ''
Or use data to pass datetime value